# Web Based Email Renderer

Tags: html, email, browser

My company has a requirement to render MIME encoded emails (HTML) in a browser window.  This isn't part of an MUA, but a tool we need to add to our product.  I've looked all over the net for a product/library and I'm not finding one.

Has anyone used anything to render emails in a browser window?

Comment: Not tested this, but maybe you could save the emails into .MHT files. MHTML format: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML

Comment: I'm not following your question. You are trying to display emails (*which are **HTML** files*) in a browser (which supports HTML)? Where's the problem?

Comment: @David The HTML often contains references to other attachments of the email; pretty much anywhere a URL can go would need to be checked, and replaced with the actual content url. Additionally, the HTML requires a certain amount of sanitization to be safely displayed to the user.

Comment: http://www.putsmail.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention a language, so I'll assume you're flexible.

- **Python** would be my preferred solution - it has [email parser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html), and [pyzmail](http://www.magiksys.net/pyzmail/). The latter is a bit easier to use, the former is more compatible.
- **PHP** has [MailParse](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mailparse.php) and [Mime Mail Parser](https://code.google.com/p/php-mime-mail-parser/).
- **Ruby** has [Mail](https://github.com/mikel/mail).

Just extract the HTML using the relevant function in whatever library you go with, then either render it straight to the browser, or save it on the filesystem and return a link. You can't 'link' to attachments from the email body, but you can get the attachments from the parser library, save them and generate links to the files.

Comment: it would probably have been sufficient (I left that job over 2 years ago) to replace the img src's with the encoded attachment data as dataURI's, since it was an internal tool and we could have targetted a specific browser.   Do you believe that would be possible with one of the libraries you're talking about.  The project was a Perl project, but I could never get it to work with the libraries I found.

Comment: Seeing how Perl was constructed to parse text-based files, I'm curious why it wasn't the leading consideration in your languages

Comment: I think the second part is where the issues are; a great example is in a webmail client mailur - https://github.com/naspeh/mailur/blob/master/mailur/parser.py it cleans the HTML for bad tags and attributes, relinks any content in the message, and provides it ready to insert into your storage

Comment: @vol7ron mostly because Perl has taken out a restraining order against me. I'm not allowed within text-editing distance of any Perl package, because it usually ends up badly for everyone involved. That said, I'm sure it would do the job just as well as the other languages I mentioned.

Comment: @NathanM you want to inline any reference to hosted images or files? I hadn't understood that bit from the question, sorry. What kind of sanitisation is required?

Comment: @Blowski ^^ - I should hope so, seeing how PHP and Ruby were heavily influenced by Perl.  Python was more influenced by C (but also Perl). I liken each of the languages listed as spinoffs of Perl (with different focuses), so was confused to not see Perl, since this would be right in its realm.

Comment: @Blowski  1. In a multi-part email, images can be referenced from html with the `cid:` scheme 2. If you're displaying untrusted html on your web based email client, if that includes javascript, it could expose the users credentials / locations etc.